# Terminating Python scripts in Processing framework

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2

I'm writing a Python script to use it in Processing framework. I need to cancel script execution if certain conditions are met (to save user's time). I tried to use `sys.exit(arguments)` command. The issue is that not only the script, but QGIS itself shuts down too. I also tried `quit()` but result is the same. How should I terminate script in Processing framework?

The following code is for reproduction purpose only. I don't need *ad hoc* solution for this particular case because I already have it. I need to know how to deal with this issue in general.

```
##Raster processing=group
##raster_1=raster
##raster_2=raster


from osgeo import gdal
import sys
from numpy import *
import ntpath
import re
import platform
from PyQt4 import QtGui


raster_1 = gdal.Open(raster_1)
raster_2 = gdal.Open(raster_2)

rasters_list = [raster_1, raster_2]

# create a message for the case when CRSs of rasters do not match
class WrongCRS(QtGui.QMessageBox):

  def __init__(self):
    super(WrongCRS, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):

    self.warning(self, 'Oops!',
            "Rasters must have the same CRS!\n\nExecution cancelled!", QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)

# check CRS
proj = None
for raster in rasters_list:
  new_proj = raster.GetProjection()
  if proj is None:
    proj = new_proj
  else:
    if proj != new_proj:
      WrongCRS()
      sys.exit('CRSs do not match!')
    else:
      continue
```

Comment: it might be helpful to get to know a bit more about your code(not only for reproduction). Are you trying to interrupt within a `for`loop or a `try-catch` phrase? I often end my script with writing `none` into all open files/variables.

Comment: @Curlew, I added relevant part of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible (for now at least) to terminate Processing python script and leave QGIS itself untouched. It was suggested by @gene to use sys.exitfunc() to terminate main function. However I find it more useful to use just `return message` to just end function normally. Here is pseudo code:

```
class ErrorMessage(...):
  .....

def checkFunction(parameter):
  if parameter == condition:
    return False
  else:
    return True

def jobFunction(...):
  ...
  if parameter_1 == condition_1:
    return False

  result = ...
  return result

def main(...):
  if not checkFunction(parameter):
    return ErrorMessage(...)

  result = jobFunction(...)
  if result == False:
    return ErrorMessage(...)

  return result

main(...)
```

Answer (score 6):

- **first thing**, `osgeo.gdal` is for pure Python scripting:

  ```
  from osgeo import gdal  
  raster  = gdal.Open('your.tif')   
  raster.GetProjection()
  ```

Everything else is a problem of osgeo, and not of PyQGIS, since you use 2 QGIS existing layers:

```
 ##raster_1=raster  
 ##raster_2=raster
```

you don't need it. To process the layers, the correct code is:

```
raster_1 = processing.getobject(raster_1)   
raster_2 = processing.getobject(raster_2)
```

an the crs is given by:

```
new_proj = raster.crs()
```

- **second thing**, you cannot load a raster in QGIS without projection (if not yet existing, it is chosen by QGIS, according to some criteria):

[image]

So your first condition `if proj is None:`,  is unnecessary and your script become (you don't need a list with only two layers):

```
raster_1 = processing.getobject(raster_1)
raster_2 = processing.getobject(raster_2)
if raster_1.crs()==raster_2.crs():
     action
else:
     WrongCRS()
```

and the script terminate  by himself.

---

in the last version of the processing module, it is now:

```
processing.getObjects()
```

---

For terminate the script, you can embed your script in a function and use `sys.exitfunc()`
(I use the Python console to to see the results)

**example**:

```
import atexit
.....
def all_done():
    message = '- Rasters must have the same CRS!\n\nExecution cancelled!'
    print message   
atexit.register(all_done)
raster_1 = processing.getObject(raster_1)
raster_2 = processing.getObject(raster_2)
def main():
    if raster_1.crs() != raster_2.crs():
         sys.exitfunc()
    else:
          message = "ok"
          print message
          continue
main()
```

Result in the Python console:

[image]

Comment: FYI `processing.getobjects()` doesn't work any more. Thank you for advices on my code improvements, but I didn't ask for it and frankly they are pointless, cause I didn't ask for them and I had my reasons for that structure.Have you actually tested your own solution? After `else: WrongCRS` there are lines of code in my script and they will be executed if the script is not terminated. Finally where is the answer for my question that I expressed quite clear: **how to terminate script in processing framework in general?**. I was very close to down-vote your answer.

Comment: If you use the last version of processing, it is now `processing.getObjects()` (look at [Create_tiling_from_vector_layer.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/script/scripts/Create_tiling_from_vector_layer.py)) but down-vote if you want.

Comment: ok, good to know. BTW it was't me who down-voted your answer.

Comment: It is a problem of PyQT4, look at [simple IPython example raises exception on sys.exit()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888045/simple-ipython-example-raises-exception-on-sys-exit)

Comment: I don't see what is your point and how does that issue related to mine. I don't have any errors or exceptions. In fact if I start QGIS in console the final message I see is the one from `sys.exit()` there are no errors or segfaults.

Comment: `sys.exit()`kills Python and QGIS. I found another solution: embedding the code in a function and using `sys.exitfunc()`(see above)