# Processing Script: now gives error in QGIS 2.2

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing

I recently updated to QGIS version 2.2, and am now getting an error when running Processing scripts that worked previously (in version 2.0.1).

```
Uncaught error while executing algorithm
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISVA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py",    line 202, in execute
self.processAlgorithm(progress)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISVA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 252, in processAlgorithm
exec script in ns
File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getobject'
```

I believe it's this line of code causing the error, but i'm not sure how to modify it to work with QGIS 2.2:

```
indivLayer = processing.getobject(Couche_compteurs_individuels)
```

Comment: What is the related code? For instance, what is processing and and .getobject()? getobject() isn't found in the API documentation, and I would expect it to be getObject() if it was a valid method.

Comment: getobject(obj): Returns a QGIS object (a layer or table) from the passed object, which can be a filename or the name of the object in the QGIS Table of Contents. A command in the processing package: http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html?highlight=processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of processing use getObject instead of getobject:

```
 processing.getObject(Couche_compteurs_individuels)
```

Look at [How to terminate Python scripts in Processing framework properly?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81530/how-to-terminate-python-scripts-in-processing-framework-properly/81573#81573)