# Is it possible to stop an algorithm midway through processing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, algorithm

This question come about do to an annoying though infrequent issue I have been having in QGIS. On occasion, I will begin processing a tool that will take some time to run but realize midway through that I do not want to complete the algorithm with the provided inputs. Previously I have had to end the task with my task manager since I have found that closing out of the window does not always stop the process. Ending in this way can cause data loss sometimes. Does anyone know of a way, inside the QGIS console, to stop a process?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to terminate Python scripts in Processing framework properly?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81530/how-to-terminate-python-scripts-in-processing-framework-properly)