# Terminating Python Script in QGIS console?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

How do I terminate any script in QGIS python console window?

ctrl + c does not work

Comment: did you see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81530/how-to-terminate-python-scripts-in-processing-framework-properly  and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81530/how-to-terminate-python-scripts-in-processing-framework-properly

Comment: I want to use it for testing the script, what I were looking for was some shortcut / hotkey like the one in IDLE, say if the scripts goes into an infinite loop, then I can stop it and make changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try some of the other `CTRL` options that you can find in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460045/1147688) to Stack Overflow question [Stopping python using ctrl+c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364173/stopping-python-using-ctrlc). There I also explain in depth why certain ones does not work, while others do.