# Stopping script processing without shutting down QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm looking for a way to abort a script execution if a sql query returns some results. I've found a few solutions on the forum but all of them lead to shutting down QGIS (thing I precisely want to avoid).

This question has already been discussed at [How to terminate Python scripts in Processing framework properly?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81530/how-to-terminate-python-scripts-in-processing-framework-properly) and the conclusion was that it was not possible yet.

7 years later, I'm wondering if this has eventually been made possible?

My script:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(db_key)

cur = conn.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("""
-- 
SELECT * FROM a.table1 WHERE ps_code like 'test_erreur'
""")

except:
    print ("Can't run this SQL query")

rows = cur.fetchall()

if rows is None: 
    print("No error found")
if len(rows) > 0:
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Erreur", "Script processing had to be stopped because errors has been detected", level=Qgis.Critical, duration=30)
    for row in rows:
        print (row)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: And a Python Error like `raise ValueError` ?

Comment: Remove sys.exit()

Comment: J.Monticolo you are definitely faster than google to provide me with great tips and answers ! :D

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please don't re-ask questions, even if they were first asked many years ago; these are your [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010).